# unicity of separator element in continuity axiom

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Is this statement equivalent to the continuity axiom of real numbers?

If $A$ and $B$ are two nonempty subsets of $\mathbb R$ such that $a\in A, b\in B \implies a\le b$ then there exists $c\in \mathbb R$ such that $a\in A, b\in B \implies a\le c\le b$.

The doubt is about the fact that $B$ is not required to be the complement of $A$ and that the number $c$ is not required to be unique. Maybe hyper-reals do satisfy this statement?

Comment: One should answer yes to the first question after reading J. Marsden _Elementary Classical Analysis_ (1974), exercise 6, p. 28 .

Comment: As to the second question, I believe not because the field of hyper-reals is not archimedean.